# How to use brk()/sbrk() with gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm writing my own study implementation of `malloc()` using `brk(2)`. However, when I try to compile the code with gcc 4.8.4 on Linux Mint 17.2:

```
gcc -g -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic zalloc.c -c -o zalloc.o
```

I've got the "implicit declaration of function brk" error:

```
zalloc.c:30:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘sbrk’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

I'm already using

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

In the file that uses `brk()`.

Should I link a specific library with `-l` or `-L` ? In `man brk`, there is a cryptic reference to `Feature Test Macro requirements` for glibc:

```
Since glibc 2.12:
               _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE ||
                   (_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 ||
                       _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED) &&
                   !(_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600)
           Before glibc 2.12:
               _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 || _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
```

Is it necessary to define one of these macros to use brk() ?

Comment: You could also invoke gcc with `-std=gnu99`, I think.

Comment: @EOF that's the right answer. It now works. You should make it the answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
-std=gnu99
```

If EOF adds an answer I'll delete this one and upvote his.

Answer (score 0):

On the man page you can read this

> "Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc"

You need to defined _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500.
But clang write

> warning: "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use
>   _DEFAULT_SOURCE"

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
```

The definition need to be BEFORE #include <unistd.h>